# Does the C++ standard have anything to say when it comes to dynamic linking?

Tags: c++

I'm interested in whether there are any sort of restrictions when it comes to dynamic linking, or if it even has any notion of dynamic linking.

E.g. it could be reasonable to demand that the non-local variables in implicitly linked libraries must satisfy the initialization rules for non-local variable. But of course, this would require there be any sort of concept of dynamic linking to be in the standard, and I can't find a case of that.

Comment: Not sure if I completely understand this question but.. any (dynamically) linked library will be compiled. So _any_ variable will either be initialized with the value it was assigned to, or it will be initialized with its default value. So, in the end any compiled executable or library is simply going to follow the respective C++ standard it has been compiled under. Please note that I haven't touched C++ for years but if I get your question right, this would be my answer. Maybe somebody else can clarify this better hence I provide just a comment here.

Comment: @StefanFalk C++ allows non-constant initializers; those must be executed at runtime.

Comment: I think you might be correct and the example of the initialization I gave is not a good one.

I'm not completely sure though... I'd think it might make sense not to always enforce initialization of global variables when it comes to compiling a library, i.e. a compiler would do something slightly different when emitting a library. It might make sense to let the user who loads the library handle this themselves, for some reason.

Comment: @pk1234d also, can you clarify what kind of dynamic linking are you interested? There's the one where the `.dll`/`.so` are loaded by the OS when the main executable starts, and there's the flavor when the program calls `LoadLibrary`/`dlopen` at a later point at runtime. Even though the standard doesn't say anything about either, the former usually just works, whereas the later is incompatible with the way some C++ features are commonly implemented. (...thread locals entered the chat...)

Comment: @YakovGalka I'm mostly interested in the implicit linking variation (no explicit call to `LoadLibrary` or `dlopen`). I'd be interested to know how a dll/so build differs from an executable - I'd assume that at least the dynamic initialization of non-locals is 'omitted' from dll/so builds and must become a part of some initialization function that runs when the library is loaded. While in an executable, it can be contained directly before `main` is entered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard has no concept of separation into libraries at all, neither in the form of dynamic or static linking. It considers a program to consist only of a set of translation units (mapping to individual object files compiled from individual source units). They have no additional properties or organization (aside from the what C++20 modules added).

> E.g. it could be reasonable to demand that the non-local variables in implicitly linked libraries must satisfy the initialization rules for non-local variable.

The standard is written in such a way that implementations using dynamic linking can satisfy the behavior required by the standard. But the standard draws the line not between libraries, but between translation units. Initialization rules are the same for all translation units and dynamic linking can be implemented to follow them.

For example, dynamic initialization of a non-inline static-storage duration non-local variable is not required to happen at program start, i.e. before `main` is entered. Instead it is *implementation-defined* (i.e. the compiler should document the behavior) whether the initialization is deferred until the first (non-initialization) odr-use of such a variable defined in the same translation unit. This basically permits the implementation to delay initialization of all such variables in a dynamic library (which is composed of multiple translation units) until the library is loaded or used for the first time.

See [deferred dynamic initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization#Deferred_dynamic_initialization) for details.

The rules are also written in such a way that the order of initialization needs to be consistent with the source code order only inside individual translation units. That means that e.g. dynamic linking can also work by just having in each library an initializing function that calls each dynamic initialization required by variables in the library and then having the linked program or program loader call these per-library initializing functions in an arbitrary order before `main` or when a new library is loaded.

---

However, dynamic linking typically includes a lot of features that go beyond what the standard defines.

For example in the standard there is no notion of visibility of symbols. The standard does not have any mechanism to e.g. have two functions of equal signature with the same name in the same namespace have different implementations in different translation units with each implementation used only in subsets of translation units (i.e. limit the visibility of the implementations to a dynamic library). That would just be an IFNDR program with under the standard for ODR violations. (IFNDR meaning *ill-formed, no diagnostic required*, which effectively means about the same as *undefined behavior* for all inputs)

However, the standard has a similar concept on the level of individual translation units: *internal linkage*.